# Problem on opening a modal when closing an other

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

This is my scenario.
I have a modal (Modal A) with 2 button in the footer: Save and Close.
When I click on "Save" button, I need to close the modal A and open the modal B, and it works with this code:

Modal A:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalAddressees">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Select Addresses</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                [....]
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer bg-whitesmoke br">
                <button type="button" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#saveBtn").on('click', function () {
        $('#modalAddressees').modal('hide')
        $('#modalAddressees').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#modalNewAddress').modal('show');
        })
    });
});
```

But after I close the Modal B and I open again Modal A, if I click on close button (to dismiss it) it open again the Modal B, why? In my Javascript I choose to open Modal B only when "Save" button is clicked, not the close one. Could you help me please?

Here my test with same error: https://jsfiddle.net/swim89/xso0jw9k/2/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I changed my code like this:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#saveBtn").on('click', function () {
        $('#modalAddressees').modal('hide');
        $('#modalNewAddress').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Javascript

```
$().ready(function () {
    const modalA = $('#modalAddressees');
    $("#saveBtn").on('click', function () {
        modalA.modal('hide')
        modalA.off('hidden.bs.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            modalA.modal('show');
        })
    });
});
```

or

```
$().ready(function () {
    const modalA = $('#modalAddressees');
    modalA.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        modalA.modal('show');
    });
    $("#saveBtn").on('click', function () {
        modalA.modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: when I try your code (both) if I click on close button, will reopen modalA, if I click on save button, will reopen modalA, if I close the modalA from X on top-right, will reopen again modalA...

Answer (score 0):

on hidden bs modal id: modalAddAdress show modal id: modalNewAdress

```
$('#modalAddressees').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#modalNewAddress').modal('show');
 })
```

seems it's works like you wrote.